# Error Calling Initialized Variables In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Building a Rails 3.2 app with Ruby 1.9.
I am trying to write a helper method that initializes 3 variables and when i try to call the initialized variables from my view i get an "undefined method" error.

Method In Helper File

```
module StoreHelper
class Status
def initialize(product)
product_sales = product.line_items.total_product_sale.sum("quantity")
#avoid nil class errors for vol2 and 3. volume 1 can never be nil
if product.volume2.nil?
    product.volume2 = 0
end
if product.volume3.nil?
    product.volume3 = 0
end
 #Promo status logic
if (product_sales >= product.volume2) && (product_sales < product.volume3)
  @level3_status = "Active"
  @level2_status = "On!"
  @level1_status = "On!"
elsif (product_sales >= product.volume3)
   @level3_status = "On!"
   @level2_status = "On!"
   @level1_status = "On!"
else  @level3_status = "Pending"
end 
end
```

I then attempt to call the the initialized variable @level3_status like so

```
 <%=level3_status (product)%>
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long are you programming with ruby? You have to create a new instance of your class to access the instance outside. Take a look at these basics: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_variables.htm

**UPDATE**

From the link above..

Ruby Instance Variables:

Instance variables begin with @. Uninitialized instance variables have the value nil and produce warnings with the -w option.

Here is an example showing usage of Instance Variables.

```
class Customer
  def initialize(id, name, addr)
    @cust_id=id
    @cust_name=name
    @cust_addr=addr
   end

  def display_details()
    puts "Customer id #@cust_id"
    puts "Customer name #@cust_name"
    puts "Customer address #@cust_addr"
  end
end

# Create Objects
cust1=Customer.new("1", "John", "Wisdom Apartments, Ludhiya")
cust2=Customer.new("2", "Poul", "New Empire road, Khandala")

# Call Methods
cust1.display_details()
cust2.display_details()
```

That´s how you can work with ruby and instance variables. More details are in the link.

In your case I think you have another "error", you mixed a few things.. where is your helper class? Under the app/helpers/store_helper.rb? In this file you should just add view helpers. If I am right with my intuitions I would solve your problem like following:

app/helpers/store_helper.rb

```
module StoreHelper

  def get_level_states(product)
    product_sales = product.line_items.total_product_sale.sum("quantity")
    product.volume2 = 0 if product.volume2.nil?
    product.volume3 = 0 if product.volume3.nil?

    levels = {}
    if (product_sales >= product.volume2) && (product_sales < product.volume3)
      levels[:1] = "On!"
      levels[:2] = "On!"
      levels[:3] = "Active!"
    elsif product_sales >= product.volume3
      levels[:1] = "On!"
      levels[:2] = "On!"
      levels[:3] = "On!"
    else
      levels[:3] = "Pending"
    end

    levels
  end

end
```

app/views/your_views_folder/your_view.html.erb

to get the different level state:

```
<% levels = get_level_states(product) %>

<%= levels[:1] %> # will print the level 1
<%= levels[:2] %> # will print the level 2
<%= levels[:3] %> # will print the level 3
```

Comment: Sorry if this was a silly question, i've only been programming, Ruby or any other language for that matter, for  about 3 months now.  not sure what you mean by create a new instance of the class and i didnt see anything about that in the linke. can you explain further?

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if I am not right with my intuitions what you really want :)..

Comment: Your assumptions were spot on and your solution helped. Thanks!